# Create generic list from an object and its list using lambda

Tags: c#, list, lambda

I am trying to create a "flat" generic list of objects from an object with a list of items in it. Ill explain below:

```
public class Student
{
   public string Name;
   public string Age;
}

public class Classroom
{
   public string Name;
   public List<Student> Students;
}
```

I now have a list of Classroom objects called  `List<Classroom> Classrooms` each populated with a list of students, all i need is a generic list that will have the following information for each classroom and every student in all classrooms:

```
{Classroom.Name, Student.Name, Student.Age}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534336(v=vs.100).aspx) Linq extension:

```
Classrooms.SelectMany(classroom => classroom.Students.Select(student => new 
{ 
    ClassroomName = classroom.Name, 
    StudentName = student.Name, 
    StudentAge = student.Age 
}))
```

Comment: Perfect, it was the selectMany that i was missing, @Blogrbeard im sure yours will also work, i was looking for a lambda answer, but thanks too!

Answer (score 2):

You can get what you want like this:

```
var results = (
    from room in Classrooms
    from student in room.Students
    select new { Room=room.Name, student.Name, student.Age }
).ToList();
```

This gets you a list of instances of an anonymous type. It might be better to declare a class and use that instead - `new MyClass(room.Name, etc)` instead of `new { Room=room.Name, etc }`.